# Registering and update model in a single API call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.net API 2 application with a register method, which basically does the following:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = user.email, Email = user.email };
UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "SomeRole");
```

In the same controller, I would like to assign a model class to the application user, for example:

```
var parent = db.Parents.Find(parentToCreate.id);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This gives me an error that the user name is already taken. I know that the issue is relating to there being two model trackers, one for the `UserManager.CreateAsync` and one for updating the db. Will it be alright to create users without using `CreateAsync` or is there another way to avoid this error?

Note that I think that this could be achieved by putting a Parent property on the account property, but not all accounts are parents, so I do not want to do this solution. A parent has an account, so there is an account property on the parent.

As requested, the full register method is as follows:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("RegisterParent")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult>RegisterParent(ParentRegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.email, Email = model.email };


        Parent parentToCreate = new Parent();
        db.Parents.Add(parentToCreate);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();


        try
        {
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password);

           // The following two lines give an error
           parentToCreate.account = user;
           // the above two lines give an error
           UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "ParentRole");
           db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
            // e returns here with message 
        }

        return Ok(200);

    }
```

Comment: Where do you invoke `UserManager.CreateAsync`?

Comment: I've updated the question with hopefully enough information to reproduce, displaying where UserManager.CreateAsync is called.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of `userToAssign`? It seems to be unused.

Comment: As yes, it is unused, apologies. I have tried the next line to be: parentToCreate.account = userToAssign; instead, becuase I wondered if that would solve the issue (hoping that the entity framework context tracker would be fresh on this object, so that I wouldn't get the above error. This attempt at a solution did not work.

Comment: any advice on what else is missing from this question would be appreciated.

Comment: @Sam, Why are you using the `user.Id` before having created the user? `user.Id` wont be populated till after the user is created. The order of your flow seems misaligned. You are trying to do too many things at once. simplify the process

Comment: IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password);
is called before I create a user with:
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "ParentRole");
This seems to work alright. If I comment out the line that is stated to give an error then the flow works without issues.

Comment: @Sam ok you updated the code that I was referring to. disregard that last statement.

Comment: @Sam use two separate `DbContext` instances.  Is the db injected?

Comment: yes, I simplified the code to make it less confusing my deleting code that is not necessary as you suggested. I did not change the order. 

I am using the account controller which comes ootb with a new web api 2 project. This has a userManager and I have added a context object so that I can access the other models in my context. 
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

'ApplicationUserManager userManager' is passed in via the constructor.

Comment: There is a single instance configured per request in startup as follows: 

            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

Comment: I think you are correct that the issue is with using two context objects by the way. I am stuck on how to handle this  with a single context object though.

Comment: a very good point

Comment: I will edit the question. This does make my code cleaner and faster (thanks!). Unfortunately, this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153386/discussion-between-nkosi-and-sam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified example based on minimal example provided in OP.

Based on conversation to clarify current design the `Parent` model would need to be updated to have a proper code first Foreign Key relationship

```
public class Parent { 
    //...other properties

    //Foreign key 
    public string accountid { get; set; }
    //navigation property
    [ForeignKey("accountid")] 
    public ApplicationUser account { get; set; } 
}
```

With that then you only need to assign the user id when creating the parent.

Refactoring/abstracting out specific responsibilities.

```
public interface IParentService {
    Task AddParentAsync(ApplicationUser user);
}

public class ParentService : IParentService {
    ApplicationDbContext db;
    public ParentService(ApplicationDbContext db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public async Task AddParentAsync(ApplicationUser user) {
        Parent parentToCreate = new Parent() {
            //...set other properties
            accountid = user.Id
        };
        db.Parents.Add(parentToCreate);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Next separating the action into distinct processes to avoid concurrency issues.

```
public class AccountController : ApiController {
    ApplicationUserManager userManager;
    IParentService parentService;
    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IParentService parentService) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.parentService = parentService;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("RegisterParent")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterParent(ParentRegisterBindingModel model) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.email, Email = model.email };
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password);
        if (result.Succeed) {
            try {
                await userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "ParentRole");
                await parentService.AddParentAsync(user);
                return Ok();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                userManager.Delete(user.Id);
                Console.Write(e);
                // e returns here with message 
                return BadRequest(); //OR InternalServerError();
            }
        } else {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }            
    }
}
```

You would obviously register dependencies with the DI framework to allow for proper injection.